# Right package for JSON-GLib development headers

Tags: application-development, pidgin, configure

During configuration of one project, I got the error:

```
checking for JSON... no
no
configure: error: 
You must have JSON-GLib >= 0.14.0 development headers installed to build.

make: *** [config.status] Error 1
```

The `configure` script contains such strings:

```bsh
$ cat configure | grep json-glib
    { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors \"json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0\""; } >&5
  ($PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0") 2>&5
  pkg_cv_JSON_CFLAGS=`$PKG_CONFIG --cflags "json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0" 2>/dev/null`
    { { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: \$PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors \"json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0\""; } >&5
  ($PKG_CONFIG --exists --print-errors "json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0") 2>&5
  pkg_cv_JSON_LIBS=`$PKG_CONFIG --libs "json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0" 2>/dev/null`
            JSON_PKG_ERRORS=`$PKG_CONFIG --short-errors --print-errors --cflags --libs "json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0" 2>&1`
            JSON_PKG_ERRORS=`$PKG_CONFIG --print-errors --cflags --libs "json-glib-1.0 >= 0.14.0" 2>&1`
```

So I assumed I need package `json-glib-1.0` but it seems to be installed:

```
$ apt-cache policy json-glib-1.0
libjson-glib-1.0-common:
  Installed: 0.16.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.16.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.16.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libjson-glib-1.0-0-dbg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.16.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.16.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
gir1.0-json-glib-1.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
gir1.2-json-glib-1.0:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
libjson-glib-1.0-0:
  Installed: 0.16.2-1ubuntu1
  Candidate: 0.16.2-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 0.16.2-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Does anyone know which package should I install? In the case it does matter, the source is Pidgin 3.0 development branch. Everything I found in Google is only [a message about changing json-glib to 0.14 version](http://pidgin.im/pipermail/commits/2013-January/021918.html).

As raaz suggested below, I downloaded, converted and installed RPM via `alien`. But the `configure` script produces the same error, even with the newest version of package.

```
$ dpkg -L json-glib-devel | grep include
/usr/include
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-gvariant.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-builder.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-gobject.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-version.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-parser.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-reader.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-path.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-enum-types.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-glib.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-generator.h
/usr/include/json-glib-1.0/json-glib/json-types.h
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The development files for `json-glib` can be installed through the normal software repositories, there's no need to get them from a different distro and converting packages!

```
sudo apt-get install libjson-glib-dev
```

When compiling an application and the configure script complains about missing dependencies, you'll need the development files (in 99% of the cases). In Ubuntu these are marked by a `-dev` at the end of the package name.

Comment: Thanks Timo. I was already directed to it on #pidgin and #ubuntu-motu channels at freenode.net. However, your answer is correct, so I'm marking it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I have found it but in RPM format. You still have a chance . convert that rpm to deb.

Download RPM with

```
wget http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/i386/os/Packages/json-glib-devel-0.14.0-1.fc16.i686.rpm
```

for 32-bit architecture, and

```
wget http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/16/Fedora/x86_64/os/Packages/json-glib-devel-0.14.0-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

for 64-bit architecture.

Then convert that into deb with alien

```
sudo apt-get install alien
alien -k json-glib-devel-0.14.0-1.fc16.<architecture>.rpm
```

That will create a .DEB and you can install a DEB with

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

Hope that helps. Any doubts/problems let me know.

Comment: [let us go in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)